# How to have another value data in JSON?

Tags: python, json

I have the following list:

```
label_list_SR1 =  ['17011', '17022']
label_list_SR2 =  ['18011', '18022', '18033']
```

**I. JSON content**

The following JSON content which I returned from my router using **RESTCONF**:

```
{
    "Cisco-IOS-XE-native:name": [
        {
            "pname": "SR1",
            "mode": "enable",
            "index": [
                {
                    "idx": 1,
                    "next-label": 17011
                },
                {
                    "idx": 2,
                    "next-label": 17022
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "pname": "SR2",
            "mode": "enable",
            "index": [
                {
                    "idx": 1,
                    "next-label": 18022
                },
                {
                    "idx": 2,
                    "next-label": 18033
                },
                {
                    "idx": 3,
                    "next-label": 18044
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**II. Building JSON file**

The function `make_json(label_list, SR_path)` build a JSON file `data.json` in order to send it to the next function.

```py
def make_json(label_list, SR_path):
    key_1 = 'Cisco-IOS-XE-native:explicit-path'
    key_2 = "name"
    key_2_1 = "pname"
    key_2_2 = "mode"
    key_2_3 = "index"
    data = {
        key_1: {
            key_2: [
                {
                    key_2_1: SR_path,
                    key_2_2: "enable",
                    key_2_3: [
                        {
                            "idx": 1,
                            "next-label": 22
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }

data_1 = {
        key_1: {
            key_2: [
                {
                    key_2_1: SR_path,
                    key_2_2: "enable",
                    key_2_3: [

                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
for i in range(len(label_list)):
    str_add = {'idx': i + 1, 'next-label': label_list[i]}
    data_1[key_1][key_2][0]['index'].append(str_add)

with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    return json.dump(data_1, outfile, indent=4)
```

**III. HTTPS PUT**

Because I want to use **HTTPS Request** and use **PUT**, I implemented the function `make_json(label_list, SR_path)` in order to push the `label_list_SR1` and `label_list_SR2` into my router.

```py
def put_explicit_path(self):
        filepath = 'data.json'
        with open(filepath) as fh:
            mydata = fh.read()
            urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
            https_request_index = 'https://' + self.host + '/restconf/data/Cisco-IOS-XE-native:native/ip/explicit-path'
            headers = {'Content-type': 'application/yang-data+json', 'Accept': 'application/yang-data+json'}
            r = requests.put(https_request_index, data=mydata, auth=(self.user, self.password), headers=headers, verify=False)
            if r:
                print ("New labels have been pushed")
```

When I call the function `make_json(label_list_SR1, label_list_SR1)`, then  `make_json(label_list_SR1, label_list_SR2)` it create like following:

```
    "Cisco-IOS-XE-native:name": [
        {
            "pname": "SR2",
            "mode": "enable",
            "index": [
                {
                    "idx": 1,
                    "next-label": 17011
                },
                {
                    "idx": 2,
                    "next-label": 17012
                },
                {
                    "idx": 3,
                    "next-label": 17013
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Literally, it considers only the last function. I aim to have the same JSON file which I showed in the beginning of this question in **Section. I** However, I don't see how this can be done. I believe somewhere in function `make_json(label_list, SR_path)`.

Comment: Can you just shorten your question to your current input and your desired output? Your code is pretty hard to read (and can be A LOT shorter).

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse The desired output is in **I. JSON content**. I have already implemented away to do it, but there's something missed which I aim to have to get the output.

Comment: Your function opens the file to write to *each time you call the function*, so yes, the second call will replace the contents of the file entirely. JSON is not a format that lends itself to concatenation anyway. Why are you using a file to move data between functions, anyway?

Comment: It makes much more sense to just build the data as a *Python object*, and only encode to JSON once you make the `requests.put()` call. That has the added advantage that that way you can leave the encoding to the `requests` library, as it'll encode data to JSON *for you* when you use the `json=...` argument.

Comment: @MartijnPieters because I need to push the output file using HTTPS PUT into my router. So, basically, I need full JSON file.

Comment: @TimLuka: no, `requests.put()` does not need a file. You only need JSON data. That's not the same thing. Note that you are *reading from the file* to call `requests.put()`.

Comment: @TimLuka: you could have used `json.dumps()` to just return a string, and skip the file altogether.

Comment: @TimLuka: if you passed the object `data_1` to `requests.put(..., json=...)` you'd delegate encoding your Python data structure to JSON to the `requests` library. No files needed, no `json.dumps()` needed either. You can then use additional code to further augment the dictionary with extra keys as needed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It was just easier for me just to have JSON file. I thought I would not need another implementation, Just rewrite and re-implementate the current one.

Comment: @TimLuka: you are, in my professional opinion, making it harder for yourself here by writing your data to an external file then reading it in again, all to create a JSON string.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I would appreciate if you help building the python object as the desired output.

Comment: All the code you have written can be reduced to probably 15 lines, be a lot cleaner, and a lot more bug proof if you follow @MartijnPieters recommendation and used pythons built in json functionality properly...